# Generalization of p-series using positive convex function

Tags: real-analysis

I'm wondering if the following is true:

> Suppose that $f$ is differentiable, positive, increasing, and convex on $[0, \infty)$. Furthermore, suppose that $f^\prime(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$.  Then $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{f(i)}$ converges.

I don't have any counterexamples as of yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The claim is not true. Note only the tail of the series matters. Thus $y = x (\log x)^\frac{1}{2}$ is a counterexample.